# OnTriggerEnter not working for PolygonCollider2D and BoxCollider2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I am running into an issue where OnTriggerEnter does not seem to be getting called. The Polygon collider should call it whenever another collider enters it, but for some reason it does not ever get called. Hoping someone could take a look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong.

PS. The

[Picture of Code attached to Object 1](https://i.stack.)

[Object 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0VhM.jpg)imgur.com/xRJrs.jpg

[Object 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15mbM.jpg)

[Scene view with two colliders overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD5Jo.jpg)

Comment: Some of those are not marked as triggers. So no it wont call the trigger methods

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure all objects have are on layers that collide with each other. Edit > Project Settings> Physics2D > CollisionMatrix at the bottom
2. Make sure all Colliders are either `Collider2D` or just `Collider`, 2D does not collide with 3D.
3. Make sure the colliders are  on Trigger (bool in Inspector) because you are using OnTriggerEnter
4. EDIT: Make sure you use OnTriggerEnter**2D** 2dPhysics dont interact with 3D physics. See 5.
5. 3D physics dont interact with 2d physics

Good luck

Comment: 1. The collision matrix has it so that they should collide with each other
2. All of the colliders are 2D
3. Shouldn't a trigger be called when a non trigger enters it?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more possibilities.